# Two div not mobile responsive using flex attribute

Tags: html, css

I have created two div that appear in different column in the desktop. How to append both the columns one after the other on mobile view?

```
<div class="footer-main" style="display:flex;">
<div><p>At IAAH we aim to provide a platform for making it easier for everyone to select products so that homemakers may express their personal style at home.
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/It's+All+About+Home+(IAAH)/@28.578941,77.315409,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xb0f8128676caaea2!8m2!3d28.578941!4d77.315409"><b>CL Gupta Retail Pvt Ltd,</b><br>
A-5A, Sector-16, Noida,
Uttar Pradesh - 201301, India</a><br><br>
<b>Contact Details</b><br>
 <a href="tel:+91-120-6774224">☎ +91-120-6774224</a><br>
 <a href="mailto:info@clgretail.com"><b>✉</b>
 info@clgretail.com</a></p></div>
<div>
<p style="text-align:left;"><b>Information & Quick Links</b><br>

<ul style="columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;">
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shipping & Assembly</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Returns & Exchanges</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
<li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Order Tracking</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Wishlist</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Care Instructions</a></li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
div.footer-main > div {
  width: 50%;
}
a {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p,
img {
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div.footer-main > div {
    width: 100%;
  }
  div.footer-main {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

After running this code on a shopify liquid code block, this is working fine on desktop but not on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to the media query like below and it is working the way you wanted:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div.footer-main > div {
    width: 95%;
  }
  div.footer-main {
    /* display: none; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```css
div.footer-main > div {
  width: 50%;
}
a {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p,
img {
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div.footer-main > div {
    width: 95%;
  }
  div.footer-main {
    /* display: none; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-main" style="display:flex;">
<div><p>At IAAH we aim to provide a platform for making it easier for everyone to select products so that homemakers may express their personal style at home.
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/It's+All+About+Home+(IAAH)/@28.578941,77.315409,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xb0f8128676caaea2!8m2!3d28.578941!4d77.315409"><b>CL Gupta Retail Pvt Ltd,</b><br>
A-5A, Sector-16, Noida,
Uttar Pradesh - 201301, India</a><br><br>
<b>Contact Details</b><br>
 <a href="tel:+91-120-6774224">☎ +91-120-6774224</a><br>
 <a href="mailto:info@clgretail.com"><b>✉</b>
 info@clgretail.com</a></p></div>
<div>
<p style="text-align:left;"><b>Information & Quick Links</b><br>

<ul style="columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;">
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shipping & Assembly</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Returns & Exchanges</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
<li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Order Tracking</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Wishlist</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Care Instructions</a></li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `flex-wrap: wrap;` where you have used a `display: flex;` this will help you to wrap content when is go outside the div. and on other ways you can use `flex-direction: column;` in media query where you want to wrap the content this will be use to shoe content in column structure.